# UISearchController issues when dismissing modally

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I am presenting a view modally when clicking a navbar button.  This view has a tableview view.  When a tableview row is clicked the view is dismissed.  I run into issues when I add a UISearchController.  When I click on an item from the results of the search bar the disappear modally but behind it is the same exact view but the tableview is displaying a fully populated view.  After a sec that view disappears modally and i am back at the nav view.  I've included a gif to help explain my issue visually. Here are code snippets.

[image: example gif]

In the view controller with the UISearchBar:

In the method cellforRowAtIndexPath

```
    //Check to see if results for search bar
if ([self.searchController isActive] && ![self.searchController.searchBar.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    restaurantCellData = self.searchResults[indexPath.row];
} else {
    restaurantCellData = self.restaurantLocations[indexPath.row];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    RestaurantLocationData *restaurantCellData = (RestaurantLocationData *)[self.restaurantLocations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (self.restaurantSelectedCallBack) {
        self.restaurantSelectedCallBack(restaurantCellData);
    }
   [self.nearByTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

in the presenting view controller I have callback block to dismiss the presented view

```
vc.restaurantSelectedCallBack = ^(RestaurantLocationData *restaurantValue) {

    self.restaurantInfo = restaurantValue;
    [[API sharedInstance] setRestaurantInfoCustom:restaurantValue];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
};

vc.searchSelectedCallBack = ^(RestaurantLocationData *restaurantValue) {
    self.restaurantInfo = restaurantValue;

    [[API sharedInstance] setRestaurantInfoCustom:restaurantValue];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
};
```

Comment: Just try this line of code before before or after dismiss viewcontroller [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];

Comment: That is deprecated as of iOS 8

Comment: searchController.active = false or dismiss searchController, because for me both are working.

Comment: thank you @JP_Mob , `searchController.active = false` helped me on viewDidDisappear

Answer (score 1):

if you have this `definesPresentationContext = true` -> Remove it or set it to **false**

and make sure add this code before dismissing the ViewController

`if searchController.isActive == true {
    // Set the search controller active to false to prevent crash
    searchController.isActive = false
}`

Comment: thank you, it helped me even without disabling `definesPresentationContext`, I have it equal `true`